# How to Resolve undefined reference to 'RAND_egd'

Tags: compiling, gcc, curl, openssl, ld

**Debian 8 Jessie, OpenSSL version 1.1.0,
cURL version: 7.50.2**

I am trying to build curl on a Linux Debian system. All stages go well up until trying to build with `make` command. The linking stage fails with the following error below:

```
  CC       ../lib/curl-nonblock.o
  CC       ../lib/curl-warnless.o
  CCLD     curl
../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to 'RAND_egd'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:771: recipe for target 'curl' failed
make[2]: *** [curl] Error 1
```

RAND_egd function is part of the OpenSSL library so I ran ldd on the libcurl.so file to make sure the OpenSSL library is found, and it is judging by the output from ldd below.

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffceb5a1000)
libnghttp2.so.14 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x00007ff9ffc05000)
libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0x00007ff9ff9d1000)
libssh2.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh2.so.1 (0x00007ff9ff7a8000)
libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007ff9ff53a000)
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007ff9ff0af000)
liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007ff9feea0000)
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007ff9fec4e000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff9fea33000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff9fe688000)
libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007ff9fe3a6000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff9fe1a2000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff9fdf85000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007ff9fdd6e000)
libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007ff9fdb52000)
libgnutls-deb0.so.28 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls-deb0.so.28 (0x00007ff9fd833000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffa0009e000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007ff9fd621000)
libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007ff9fd3db000)
libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007ff9fd1c7000)
libnettle.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.4 (0x00007ff9fcf95000)
libhogweed.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.2 (0x00007ff9fcd66000)
libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007ff9fcae3000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007ff9fc8db000)
```

So the library is there. I also checked the rand.h file in the include directory of OpenSSL and of course the function declaration is there, so it should be defined in the library. How can I find the cause of and resolve this error?

Comment: When configure is run, it checks for `RAND_egd` and it then generates `lib/curl_config.h` with a `#define HAVE_RAND_EGD` if it was indeed found. In a standard build of OpenSSL >= 1.1.0, that function is not present. So I don't know how you ended up with that define present in the curl build, but not in openssl. Multiple OpenSSL installs that confuse matters?

Comment: @DanielStenberg thank you and it is an honor to receive an answer from you. After trying to figure out the problem, I could not so I cleaned and built again, and that solved the problem. I did indeed have another earlier version of OpenSSL installed.

Answer (score 0):

> How to Resolve undefined reference to 'RAND_egd'

I believe you should now call `RAND_add_egd`. Also see [simplifying rand_egd API](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-dev/2016-January/004091.html) on the openssl-dev mailing list.

The code you are compiling should have a guard for OpenSSL 1.1.0. Maybe something like:

```
#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER >= 0x10100000L

    int rc = RAND_egd(<path>);
    ...

#else

    int rc = RAND_add_egd(<path>);
    ...

#endif
```

Daniel is usually very good about keeping up with OpenSSL. It sound like you are getting a distribution's down-level version of something.

According to [cURL Issue 763](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/763), cURL first added support for openssl-1.1.0-dev at least in April, 2016. The full change log is at [cURL Changelog](https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html).

---

Related, you should probably move on from cURL 7.50.2. It has [12 known vulnerabilities](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/vuln-7.50.2.html). It looks like 7.51.0 was released on November 2, 2016.

Answer (score -1):

My case in **Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (Xenial Xerus)**, that error occurred when I built the **php-7.4** source with **openssl 1.1.1m**.

So, I downloaded and built the **egd** (in my case **egd-0.9**), based on this reference (contains download link) [OpenSSL - RAND_egd](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/RAND_egd.html), and rebuilt the PHP source and it's working in my case.